# Visualizing a 4D transpose

Tags: algorithm, numpy, transpose

I've been trying to understand the 4D array transpose and can't seem to figure out what's happening. Can someone explain to me how the transpose logic works for 4D arrays? I understood the reshape but couldn't figure out the mapping of input to output elements. If you could provide me with a pseudo-code for the transpose algorithm (or a C implementation), that would be great.

Example:

```
a = np.arange(60).reshape(1, 4, 5, 3)
print(a)
print(a.transpose(0, 3, 1, 2))
```

Output:

4D array:

```
 [[[[ 0  1  2]
   [ 3  4  5]
   [ 6  7  8]
   [ 9 10 11]
   [12 13 14]]

  [[15 16 17]
   [18 19 20]
   [21 22 23]
   [24 25 26]
   [27 28 29]]

  [[30 31 32]
   [33 34 35]
   [36 37 38]
   [39 40 41]
   [42 43 44]]

  [[45 46 47]
   [48 49 50]
   [51 52 53]
   [54 55 56]
   [57 58 59]]]]
```

Transpose:

```
[[[[ 0  3  6  9 12]
   [15 18 21 24 27]
   [30 33 36 39 42]
   [45 48 51 54 57]]

  [[ 1  4  7 10 13]
   [16 19 22 25 28]
   [31 34 37 40 43]
   [46 49 52 55 58]]

  [[ 2  5  8 11 14]
   [17 20 23 26 29]
   [32 35 38 41 44]
   [47 50 53 56 59]]]]
```

Comment: Transpose makes a `view`, same data, but new shape and strides.  The logic for 4d is the same for 3d and 2d. In your example the first dimension is 1, and doesn't move, so it is 3d transpose.  The new shape is (1,3,4,5). The [0,1,2] row now goes down the planes.  For a deeper understanding you have to understand `strides`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the documentation says:

> If axes are not provided and
> `a.shape = (i[0], i[1], ... i[n-2], i[n-1])`, then
> `a.transpose().shape = (i[n-1], i[n-2], ... i[1], i[0])`

For 2D-Arrays, this simply means that a shape of `(a, b)` becomes `(b, a)`. For 3D, this means that `(a, b, c)` becomes `(c, b, a)`. Here's a simple example:

`np.arange(24).reshape([2, 3, 4])`

> [[[ 0  1  2  3]
>
> [ 4  5  6  7]
>
> [ 8  9 10 11]]
>
> [[12 13 14 15]
>
> [16 17 18 19]
>
> [20 21 22 23]]]

The same matrix transposed yields:

> [[[ 0 12]
>
> [ 4 16]
>
> [ 8 20]]
>
> [[ 1 13]
>
> [ 5 17]
>
> [ 9 21]]
>
> [[ 2 14]
>
> [ 6 18]
>
> [10 22]]
>
> [[ 3 15]
>
> [ 7 19]
>
> [11 23]]]

So it now has the shape `(4, 3, 2)`. You can see that the 'smallest' unit always has two elements, the next bigger unit has 3 elements and all in all the array has 4 elements.

You can imagine this procedure like a rotation. In order to transpose a 2D Matrix, you 'rotate' the matrix counterclockwise. Rows becomes columns and vice-versa.

In order to transpose a 3D-Matrix, you need to rotate once more 'on the table' (if you think about the matrix as a box).
Transposing a 4x4 (and also NxN) Matrix then adds one more 'rotation' to the whole process such that the shape stays in the form given above.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [151]: a = np.arange(60).reshape(1, 4, 5, 3)
In [152]: b = a.transpose(0,3,1,2)
```

`b` is a `view`, sharing the data-buffer, but with its own shape and strides:

```
In [153]: a.shape, a.strides
Out[153]: ((1, 4, 5, 3), (480, 120, 24, 8))
In [154]: b.shape, b.strides
Out[154]: ((1, 3, 4, 5), (480, 8, 120, 24))
In [155]: a.__array_interface__['data']
Out[155]: (51834880, False)
In [156]: b.__array_interface__['data']
Out[156]: (51834880, False)
```

Compare `b.shape` to `a.shape` to see how the (0,3,1,2) mapping works.  `strides` is changed in the same way.

With the `striding` mechanism, it's possible to "re-arrange" array dimensions without actually copying or moving the elements.  I don't think this is the place to explain striding in more detail.

Your example with distinct values and dimensions is the best way to 'visualize' the change.  Pick any sequence of values in `a`, e.g. [0,3,6,9,12] of the size 5 dimension, and see where they appear in the transpose.

If we make a copy of the transpose, the array has its own data-buffer, and strides is the usual increasing sequence.  That copy process has had to "iterate" through `b`, using its strides, to map values from `b` to `c`:

```
In [157]: c = b.copy()
In [158]: c.shape, c.strides
Out[158]: ((1, 3, 4, 5), (480, 160, 40, 8))
```

The "logic" for 4d transpose is no different from that of a 2d array.